# Transifex push failing all of a sudden?

Tags: jenkins, transifex

We've had our transifex set up long before I even joined my current company, and we've been able to run `tx push` command. Now all of a sudden, they've been failing. Here's the Jenkins console.

```
+ whoami
jenkins
+ cd Zift123/src/common/i18n
+ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name en-US.json
+ xargs rm
+ tx push -s --skip
Pushing translations for resource zift123.en-usjson:
HttpNotAuthorized: Forbidden
```

To eliminate Jenkins setup, I logged into the Jenkins node, and issued the commands myself. I see `~/jenkins/.transifex` with `0600` permissions, and with the correct credentials. I then did this on the command line

```
$ tx --version
0.12.2
$ cd /var/jenkins_home/workspace/transifex-test/Zift123/src/common/i18n
jenkins@3b39d23d13fe:~/workspace/transifex-test/Zift123/src/common/i18n$ ls
FINANCE en-US.json
jenkins@3b39d23d13fe:~/workspace/transifex-test/Zift123/src/common/i18n$ tx push -s --skip
Pushing translations for resource zift123.en-usjson:
HttpNotAuthorized: Forbidden
```

I know I have the correct creds since I can go to https://www.transifex.com and am able to log in using the creds in `~/.transifexrc`

What give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the user doesn't have access to the project anymore. After logging in, can you see the 'zift123' project in Transifex?

If not, you will need to get access back by asking an admin of the organization in Transifex.

Comment: Thanks. I logged in, created an organization and added the `zift123` project to it. Both are public at the moment. I still get the same error.

Comment: @ChrisF I would recommend getting in touch with the Transifex support team at this point. I'm positive it's an access right problem, and they will be able to sort out all the details and help you out.